# Explicit module exports in Frege

Tags: export, explicit, frege

I am posting this after reading the [Frege language specification](http://www.frege-lang.org/doc/Language.pdf) and looking for examples using search engines. I hope I have not overlooked an obvious answer.

I am trying to port some Haskell code to Frege and I cannot find any documentation mentioning explicit module exports. So, in my Haskell code I have something like

```
module common.Timer(start, ...)
where
...
```

but this will give a compiler error in Frege, and I have to remove the export list:

```
module common.Timer
where
...
```

But in this way I cannot control which symbols defined in the module get exported.

Is it possible to define explicit module exports in Frege? If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks ok. Before I dive deeper in what is possibly wrong, here is a quick workaround such that you can proceed working: all top-level symbols are exported by default unless it is marked `private`.

Edit after discussion: This is a current deviation from that Haskell standard that we are about to resolve.

Comment: So probably the alternate syntax I am looking for is to mark symbols as `private`?

Comment: Yes, you can just mark `private` what should not be exported. However, the original Haskell syntax should just work as well. What Frege version are you using?

Comment: Version `3.23.454-g8779d9e` which is installed by the Frege Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is one of the open issues that we are about to resolve for improved Haskell compatibility. It is slide number 31 in http://de.slideshare.net/Mittie/fregeday-roadmap-for-resolving-differences-between-haskell-and-frege-ingo-wechsung. Please feel free to file a respective github issue if it isn't already there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment: if you add that piece of information (that the Haskell syntax is not supported yet) to your answer, I can mark it as accepted. BTW, I have some experience with Haskell and I am evaluating Frege for use in a Java shop.

Comment: There is also protected which I recommend to use until we implement the Haskell syntax. Reason is that the compiler probably crashes when you have a public function that has a private type in its signature.

Comment: Cool, Giorgio, keep us posted on your progress!

Comment: @Dierk: Thanks. Where can I post? I got my application to compile and run in Eclipse. Next step is to do the same using Maven.

Comment: Great! You can use the forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/frege-programming-language and maybe include a link to a gist or a github project. If you tweet, just add @fregelang and we will RT.

Comment: @Dierk: After upgrading my `pom.xml` to use `frege` version `3.23.422-ga05a487`, I could compile and run from Maven.